# Laravel - Download Uncaught DOMException

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

i have an working download function, which used to working but now i had an error like this:

[image]

which lead to this code : `window.open(data,"_blank");`

and here is the full code :

```
$('#db-download').on('click', function(){
                const id = $('#id_view').val();
                console.log(id);
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/MediaOrder/download/" + id,
                    method: 'get',
                    success: function (data){
                        console.log((data));
                        window.open(data,"_blank");
                        // var blob = new Blob([data], { type: "application/octetstream"});
                        // window.location = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                        // tableMediaOrder.ajax.reload();
                    },
                    error: function (data) {
                        console.log('Error:', data);
                    }
                });
        });
```

the file in shown in the `console.log()`, but it seems that the file won't downloaded, can anyone know how to fix this error, or maybe anyone have a solution, appreciate the help, and thank you!.

Comment: Browsers by default will block `window.open` calls. Check if there's any "popup blocked" warning on your browser's URL bar (if on chrome or edge)

Comment: Thank you for the help!, but it seems i found a way to solve it by using, `let url =  "/MediaOrder/download/" + id;`, and then add it into the `ajax ` something like `window.location = url;`, thank you!.